# How to solve $\sqrt {1+\sqrt {4+\sqrt {16+\sqrt {64+\sqrt {256\ldots }}}}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, nested-radicals

How to solve this equation?

$$x=\sqrt {1+\sqrt {4+\sqrt {16+\sqrt {64+\sqrt {256\ldots }}}}}.$$

Answer: $x=2$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 18):

I found this answer.Is that wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Interesting! You still need to prove that it convergences. At least when $n=1$.

Comment: Actually the convergence follows from this as well. The sequence of truncated nested roots is surely increasing. And we get them from these identities by dropping a selected term, so they are bounded from above by 4.

Comment: @FMath There  is a mistake in the fifth line

Answer (score 7):

From [this paper](https://zariski.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/sr_nroots.pdf), on page $5$, equation $(20)$ and letting $x=1$ one sees that the value of your nested radical is indeed $2$.

This comes from the following:

Let $a:=\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ and $b:=\{b_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ be sequences. We will make use of the following notation:

$$R(a,b):=\sqrt{a_0 + b_0\sqrt{a_1 + b_1\sqrt{a_2 + b_2\sqrt{\ldots}}}}$$

> **Theorem:**
>
> Let $x_1,x_2,x_3 \geq 0$
>
> We define the sequences $p,q,r,s$ where:
> $$p_n = x_1x_2 + (x_2 + 2^nx_3)^2 \qquad q_n = x_1 $$
> $$r_n = x_2(x_1 + nx_3) + (x_2 + x_3)^2\qquad s_n = x_1 + nx_3$$
>
> Then
> $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = R(p,q) = R(r,s).$$

The proof is in the article and it's very interesting, but I shall not transcribe it here.

If you consider the sequences $p$ and $q$ for $x_1 = x_3 = 1$ and $x_2 = 0$ you get the desired result.

Comment: perhaps you may want to cite the specific article. Your link requires a password.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Can you find a relation between $x$ and $x^2$?

Comment: To be quite picky, one has yet to show that the sequence so defined does converge to a finite number.

Comment: @Vim: You are absolutely right. The hint is meant just to get across the 'essence' of the problem.

Comment: The convergence follows from Herschfeld's converge theorem for nested radicals http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HerschfeldsConvergenceTheorem.html since $2^{{2n}/{2^n}}$ converges to $1$.

Comment: Care to enlighten us. I don't see a useful relation. For example $x^2<1+2x$.

Answer (score 3):

just an attempt to reduce the size of the numbers...
$$
\sqrt {1+\sqrt {4+\sqrt {16+\sqrt {64+\sqrt {256\ldots }}}}}=\sqrt {1+ 2^1\sqrt{1+2^0\sqrt {1+2^{-1}\sqrt {1+2^{-2}\sqrt {1+2^{-3}\sqrt{1+\ldots }}}}}}
$$